# Lyft Developer API ride request - Additional permissions required

Tags: lyft-api

I get { "error_description": "Additional permissions required: rides.request", "error": "insufficient_permissions" } when requesting a ride on https://api.lyft.com/v1/rides.

What does "The user's payment credentials on file will be charged for the ride." imply? Do I need to set up some credit card details for payment on a Developer API account? Is this call restricted to USA area?

Answer (score 0):

> I get { "error_description": "Additional permissions required: rides.request", "error": "insufficient_permissions" } when requesting a ride on https://api.lyft.com/v1/rides.

- For requesting a Lyft ride on behalf of a user, you must have a valid user token with "rides.request" scope. The above error indicates you must have forgotten to add the "rides.request" scope while requesting the access token. Follow the steps  [here](https://developer.lyft.com/docs/authentication#section-scopes).

> What does "The user's payment credentials on file will be charged for the ride." imply? Do I need to set up some credit card details for payment on a Developer API account? Is this call restricted to USA area?

- The user's payment information with Lyft will be used for charging the ride. This means that the payment for rides done via the API will be handled completely by Lyft only.
- Lyft services are currently only available in USA/Canada regions.